# How to pass output of one function to another in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, garbage-collection, driver

I am sending output of one function which is dataframe to another function.

```
val df1 = fun1
val df11 = df1.collect
val df2 = df11.map(x =fun2( x,df3))
```

Above 2 lines are wriiten in main function. Df1 is very large so if i do collect on driver it gives outof memory or gc issue.
What r ways to send output of one function to another in spark?

Comment: why are you doing a collect here ? you could always do df1.map(x => fun2(x))

Comment: If I dont add collect then it gives null pointer exception error. Because we should collect result at driver.

Answer (score 1):

Spark can run the data processing for you. You don't need the intermediate collect step. You should just chain all of the transformations together and then add an action at the end to save the resulting data out to disk.

Calling collect() is only useful for debugging very small results.

For example, you could do something like this:

```
rdd.map(x => fun1(x))
   .map(y => fun2(y))
   .saveAsObjectFile();
```

This article might be helpful to explain more about this:

http://www.agildata.com/apache-spark-rdd-vs-dataframe-vs-dataset/

Comment: Thanks for your response. Return type of .saveAsObjectFile() is Unit. I am doing collect so that I can call function on df1. If I don't call collect it gives nullpointer exception. I do understand that collect is not effective if dataset is big. So if I call .saveAsObjectFile(), do i need to read output file to process further? Please explain.

Comment: Yes. If you need to use the save data in a future transformation, you can read the data into a new data frame. Something like:

```
sparkContext.objectFile(path)
```